# Complexity good, medium and worst

Tags: java, time-complexity

The complexity of this method (in the case of good, average, worst) created by me, which calculates the intersection of two arrays is linear? O(n)

```
public void getInt(int[] a,int[] b){
    int i=0;
int j=0;    
while(i<a.length && j<b.length){
  if(a[i]==b[j]){
    System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    i++;j++;
  }else if(a[i]<b[j]) i++;
   else if(a[i]>b[j]) j++;
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be linear.It is O(m+n), where m will be length of a and n length of b